# How to get public access to files or images from Podio API if I have image ID or File Object

Tags: podio

I have created an app on **Podio**. Items are attached to that particular app. In the items there is an option to upload an image. Now I am authenticated with the **App ID** and **App Token** from **Podio PHP API**. I get the file object and grab the thumbnail link. The thumbnail link is working on the browser where I am already logged into to Podio. But it does not working on private window. It redirects me to login page.

So my question is how could I get public access to the thumbnail link?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cannot.

Long answer: when Podio hosts a file, it checks if you're authorized to view it. So if you're logged in and viewing the url through your browser, it will show, otherwise not.

You would need to copy the image to a publicly accessible location. For example, on your web server:

```
$file = PodioFile::get($file_id);
$raw = $file->get_raw();
file_put_contents("/var/www/html/image_path/".$file->name, $raw);
```

Then you could view the file:
`http://my_domain.com/image_path/image_name.png`

Comment: Andreas, sorry, but isn't that possible with Globiflow workflow and "Public URL" for image fields? If so, I just wonder why a Globiflow founder have not mentioned this option :)

Comment: @EugenBaryshnikau the OP specifically asked about using the Podio API. Maybe they don't have GF. Or they don't want the image to be public (using GF's public image URL copies the image to the CDN making it public).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a "public url" for a file stored in image field using [Globiflow](https://www.globiflow.com) (it is now available with a premium plan). I guess it adds some kind of a proxy layer for private files. So you may add a special field to store this public URL, set/update this field value with Globiflow workflow and use this URL for public pages.

Have not found public documentation for this, but the value "Public URL" is currently available for image fields, I've specially checked.